# cron job doesn't output to nohup.out

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu, cron

i have **start.sh** bash script that is running though **CRON JOB**  on ubuntu server

**start.sh** contains bellow mentioned lines of code

path of **start.sh** is `/home/ubuntu/folder1/folder2/start.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

crawlers(){
    nohup scrapy crawl first &
    nohup scrapy crawl 2nd &
    wait $!
    nohup scrapy crawl 3rd &
    nohup scrapy crawl 4th &
    wait
}

cd /home/ubuntu/folder1/folder2/
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH

python init.py &
wait $!
crawlers
python final.py
```

my issue is if i run **start.sh** my myself on command line it outputs in **nohup.out** file

but when it executes this **bash file** through **cronjob** (although scripts are running fine) its not producing **nohup.out**

how can i get **output** of this cronjob in **nohup.out** ?

Comment: how/where are you creating this nohup.out file? remember that cron jobs' default working directory is the homedirectory of the user ID they're being run under. if you're using relative paths for this file, you'll be relative to the account's home directory, not your own shell current directory

Comment: @MarcB i am noob on linux .. 

each line is appending output in nohup e.g nohup scrapy crawl 3rd &

i added this in crontab
40 10 * * * /home/ubuntu/folder1/folder2/start.sh

Comment: FYI: the construct `python init.py &
wait $!` (spread over two lines) is pointless; drop the `&` and remove the `wait`.  It isn't a factor in your problem; it also works as written.  But it is pointless.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Why are you using `nohup`? `nohup` is a command that tells the running terminal to ignore the hangup signal. `cron`, however, has no hangup signal, because it is not linked to a terminal session.

In this case, instead of:

```
nohup scrapy crawl first &
```

You probably want:

```
scrapy crawl first > first.txt &
```

The last example also works in a terminal, but when you close the terminal, the hangup signal (`hup`) is sent,  which ends the program.