# Logs are not inserting in 'nohup.out' file

Tags: bash, shell, sh, nohup

I am executing script1.sh through crontab.

script1.sh

```
echo "Crontab is executing this script."
echo "Some code is running here."
cd cron
./script2.sh
```

'script1.sh' is invoking 'script2.sh'.

'script2.sh'

```
echo "Exceuting script2."
echo "log of script3.sh is inserting in nohup.out file."
nohup sh script3.sh &
echo "Above syntax is not logging in nohup.out file. but this syntax is 'sh script3.sh > nohup.out &' is logging in nohup.out file. Why is it so?"
```

'script2.sh' is invoking 'script3.sh',but not able to log in nohup.out file. For logging following syntax is used.

nohup sh script3.sh &

'script3.sh' contains below mention line of codes.

```
echo "Executing script3. This is just test example to simulate the things."
```

Why logs are not inserting in nohup.out file?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  "Why logs are not inserting in nohup.out file?" - What logs?  What does "script3.sh" do?  Can we see it?  Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @StephenC ... In the actual scenario 'script3.sh' will be application server logs.

Comment: @user752590 : The text _Executing script3.  ....._  should be in `nohup.out. If it isn't, what else do you see in this file? Is ``nohup.out` empty? Did you look at the **correct** nohup.out, and not at one left over from some earlier run (check the timestamp)?

Comment: @user1934428 ... "Is ``nohup.out empty?"... nohup.out is not present.

Comment: @user752590 : Did you look in the correct directory?

Comment: @user1934428 ... If i run 'script2.sh' standalone (without crontab), logs are insering in nohup.out file. But when i execute through cronjob it is not producing nohup.out file.

Comment: I didn't question the file **name** but the **directory** where it is stored. If you run it standalone, it's perhaps executed from a different directory than when run from the crontab. Perhaps it would make more sense to specify the output of the command explicitly (using an absolute path), so you can control exactly where it goes to.

Comment: the crontab doesn’t not run in interactive shell so there is no stdout or stdin for crontab. That’s the reason nohup in crontab doesn’t produce nohup.out. Please use redirections &>1 to store your logs. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145250/cron-job-doesnt-output-to-nohup-out

Comment: what is '&>1' for storing logs, Can u direct me to some link?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I meant redirect logs like cmd > logfile 2&>1. Why do you need `nohup` as crontab will run the task anyway?

Comment: could you provide us detailed information about the operating system? I have apparmor or selinux in mind as a suspect. Maybe there is a rule which does not allow cron to write in some directories.

Comment: @manishg `use redirections &>1 to store your logs.` Will it work for sure? I believe cron uses sh by default and not bash, and if I recall correctly `&>1` is bash extension.

Answer (score 4):

From `info nohup`:

> 23.4 ‘nohup’: Run a command immune to hangups
> =============================================
>
> ‘nohup’ runs the given COMMAND with hangup signals ignored, so that
> the command can continue running in the background after you log out.
> ...
> If standard output is a terminal, the command’s standard output is
> appended to the file ‘nohup.out’;
> if that cannot be written to, [waltera: the write permission/space in current dir] it is
> appended to the file ‘$HOME/nohup.out’; and if that cannot be written
> to, the command is not run.
> ...
> However, if standard output is closed, standard error terminal output
> is instead appended to the file ‘nohup.out’ or ‘$HOME/nohup.out’ as
> above.

When `cron` executes the script, stdout is not a terminal nor closed, so `nohup` has no reason to redirect any output.
Another `demo` of `nohup` without a terminal is when you start your script2.sh, that has an `nohup` command, with another `nohup`:

```
nohup ./script2.sh > masternohup.out
```

The output of `script3.sh` will be written to `masternohup.out`.

Answer (score 1):

From `man nohup`

```
...
If standard input is a terminal, redirect it from an unreadable file.
If standard output is a terminal, append output to 'nohup.out' if possible, '$HOME/nohup.out' otherwise.
If standard error is a terminal, redirect it to standard output.
To save output to FILE, use 'nohup COMMAND > FILE'.
...
```

So it could be in `$HOME/nohup.out` either way it's best to use this to control output:

```
nohup COMMAND &> FILE
```

Comment: If i run 'script2.sh' standalone (without crontab), logs are insering in nohup.out file. But when i execute through cronjob it is not producing nohup.out file.

Comment: This answer sounds plausible; if stdout is not TTY; it is e.g. a file (cannot be sure for cron...), then nohup does not (re-)redirect stdout but just keeps holding where stdout is currently written...
  
Although this may be bash specific (and `&>` redirection is convenient in interactive use), I'd recommend to use `1> FILE 2>&1` when redirecting stdout and stderr to the same file.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `nohup` in modern days.

Shell escape method allows a process to leave its process group and never receive `SIGHUP` nor any other signals directed to a process group.

In bash shell:

```
(command &>log.txt &)
```